# Multiple MOD Rewrite Rules

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

**What I'm trying to do**

I would like to redirect:

1. `www.example.com/home/place` to `www.example.com/index.php?location=place`
2. `www.example.com/home` to `www.example.com/index.php`.

**What I've done**

In `.htaccess`, I have the following line:

`RewriteRule ^home/([^/]*)$ index.php?location=$1 [L]`

This does part 1. However, with this in place, part 2 does not work. However, if I write this before the above:

`RewriteRule ^home index.php [L]`

then part 2 works, but part 1 doesn't.

Long story short, I cannot work out how to enable both rules. Is this possible, and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that

```
RewriteRule ^home index.php [L]
```

will match both examples as they both begin with "home". Try the following:

```
RewriteRule ^home/?$ index.php [L]
```

This will match /home and /home/ but not /home/foo.

Answer (score 1):

Your first rule has the parameter as "optional" because you're using a `*` instead of a `+`:

```
RewriteRule ^home/([^/]+)$ index.php?location=$1 [L]
```

Additionally, you don't have a `$` in your second rule to indicate the end of the URI:

```
RewriteRule ^home/?$ index.php [L]
```

Now the rules can be in any order you want.